# Jersey Client for Mulipart call

Tags: java, rest, multipart, jersey-client

I am using `jersey` client to make a REST call to an API which returns a Json and a PDF file in mulipart as the first and the second parts of the response.

```
final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
final WebTarget target = client.target(endPoint);
final Builder request = target.request().header("Authorization", authKey);
final Response response = request.get();
final String readEntity = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

This returns a string response with the PDF file in byte code format.
I tried to read the entity as **MultiPart** class and then I get an exception :

> Message Body Reader Not found for media type=multipart/form-data;boundary=------#### and the
> getMediaType() call on client returns multipart/form-data;boundary=------####.

What is the right way to parse this multipart response using the above client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick Google search gives you the result. You have to enable `MultiPartFeature` and you do `response.readEntity(InputStream.class)`

Got the below code from http://www.benchresources.net/jersey-2-x-web-service-for-uploadingdownloading-zip-file-java-client/

```
 // invoke service after setting necessary parameters
        clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        client =  ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
        client.property("accept", "application/zip");
        webTarget = client.target(httpURL);

        // invoke service
        invocationBuilder = webTarget.request();
        //          invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
        response = invocationBuilder.get();

        // get response code
        responseCode = response.getStatus();
        System.out.println("Response code: " + responseCode);

        if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : " + responseCode);
        }

        // get response message
        responseMessageFromServer = response.getStatusInfo().getReasonPhrase();
        System.out.println("ResponseMessageFromServer: " + responseMessageFromServer);

        // read response string
        inputStream = response.readEntity(InputStream.class);
        qualifiedDownloadFilePath = DOWNLOAD_FILE_LOCATION + "MyJerseyZippedFile.zip";
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(qualifiedDownloadFilePath);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
```

Comment: As I have a Json followed by a PDF in my response, what should be the data in client.property ?

Comment: It'll be whatever the API's `@produces` contain. You may ignore it

Answer (score 0):

I hope the following code will help you.

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(username,password ))
WebResource webResource = client.resource("URL");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("*/*").type(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).get(ClientResponse.class);
Assert.assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 200);
MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = response.getHeaders();
System.out.println("Content-Disposition  :" + headers.get("Content-Disposition"));
List<String> filename=headers.get("Content-Disposition");
file_name=filename.get(0);
file_name=file_name.substring(file_name.indexOf("\"")+1,file_name.lastIndexOf("\""));
File file=new File(file_name);
if(!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
InputStream inputStream=response.getEntityInputStream();
FileOutputStream fileStream =
        new FileOutputStream(file);
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, fileStream);
fileStream.flush();
fileStream.close();
Assert.assertTrue(file.length()>0);
//Deleting the backup file
file.delete();
```

Comment: What is the data type of webResource ?